# Hide children within the padded area

Tags: html, css, padding

When I set `overflow: hidden` on an element that has padding (`#foo` below), the overflown part of the child (`#bar` below) seems to be cut off at the border of the parent as seen in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfb4eyyo/1/).

#### HTML

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#foo{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#bar{
    background-color: green;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

How can I let the content of the child be cut off at the padding area (so that the overflow does not go into the red area in the linked result)?

Comment: Any reason for not setting the `overflow:hidden` on `#bar`? Maybe, I have not fully understood your question.

Comment: you could use `word-wrap: break-word;` - http://jsfiddle.net/dfb4eyyo/2/

Comment: @Harry For simplicity. When I set padding on an element, I want to set the effect that I mentioned on that object together without doing anything to a different object.

Comment: @sawa: Ok, I wouldn't really be recommending this approach, but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dfb4eyyo/3/) is a work-around. It replaces the right padding with a right border to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: @Harry That will work at least for some of my cases. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems too obvious, but doesn't this do that?

```
#foo{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
}

#bar{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: green;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: It is better if I can do it on `#foo` without doing anything to `#bar`. But if that is the only way, then I would have to live with it.